# SQL Server : summing two variables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to add two variables

```
DECLARE @RentsSum MONEY
SET @RentsSum = (SELECT SUM(Price)
                 FROM Rents
                 WHERE StartDate IS NOT NULL)
GO

DECLARE @SalesSum MONEY
SET @PriceSum = (SELECT SUM(Price)
                 FROM Purchases
                 WHERE DateBought IS NOT NULL)
GO

DECLARE @SalesAndRentsSum MONEY

SET @SalesAndRentsSum = @RentsSum + @PriceSum;

SELECT @SalesAndRentsSum
```

into one but I get some strange errors here...

> Must declare the scalar variable "@PriceSum".
>
> Must declare the scalar variable "@RentsSum".

Comment: Remove the `GO`. Variables do not get preserved across the batch.

Comment: i did it but still the same result

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove all the `GO` words. You have three separate batches here and the variable must be declared within the scope of that batch.

```
DECLARE @RentsSum MONEY, @SalesSum MONEY, @SalesAndRentsSum MONEY

SET @RentsSum = (SELECT SUM(Price)
                FROM Rents
                WHERE StartDate IS NOT NULL)

SET @SalesSum = (SELECT SUM(Price)
                FROM Purchases
                WHERE DateBought IS NOT NULL)

SET @SalesAndRentsSum = @SalesSum + @PriceSum

SELECT @SalesAndRentsSum
```

Comment: If you copy and paste the code above what happens @MitkoZ? Be sure to do it in a new window in SSMS.

Comment: @PriceSum in the set clause and in the adding clause get underlined by the intellisence + these erros Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Must declare the scalar variable "@PriceSum".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 11
Must declare the scalar variable "@PriceSum".

Comment: @scsimon you need to change PriceSum to SalesSum as that variable doesn't exist.

Comment: Ah nice @SeanLange. I overlooked that

Comment: @MitkoZ well a typo AND you had GO splattered all over which caused each variable to be in its own batch.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @RentsSum MONEY
DECLARE @PriceSum MONEY
DECLARE @SalesAndRentsSum MONEY

SET @RentsSum = (SELECT SUM(Price)
                FROM Rents
                WHERE StartDate IS NOT NULL)


SET @PriceSum = (SELECT SUM(Price)
                FROM Purchases
                WHERE DateBought IS NOT NULL)


SET @SalesAndRentsSum=@RentsSum+@PriceSum;
SELECT @SalesAndRentsSum
```

Comment: You need to assign a datatype to `@PriceSum`